# Inaccurate results with MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables (import_size,export_size) both contain these 2 columns (size_id,weight)
now I'm trying to get the sum of weights for each size in each table, my query looks like this

```
SELECT sum(i.weight) imports,sum(e.weight) exports,s.size 
       FROM size s 
       LEFT JOIN import_size i on s.id=i.size_id 
       LEFT JOIN export_size e on s.id=e.size_id
       GROUP BY s.size
```

now say for example in the import_size table for size 1 we have only one record but for the same size in export_size table we have 2 records, the sum of weights resulting from import_size is multiplied by 2, any thoughts?

for example:

import table has 1 record:

```
size_id 1 - weight 2
```

export table has 2 records:

```
size_id 1 - weight 2  
size_id 1 - weight 3
```

the query result:

```
imports 4 - exports 5 - size 1
```

however it should be

```
imports 2 - exports 5 - size 1
```

Comment: Can you post a few entries from your tables, as you are saying import_size is multiplied by 2, How? sqlfiddle might help.

Comment: for example, import table has 1 record: size 1 weight 2
export table has 2 records: size 1 weight 2 and size 1 weight 3
now the query result is: imports 4 exports 5 size 1

Comment: I think you have to layout your tables in the question with simple data set.

Comment: Do you want the query result to be 7?

Comment: @Mazen and what result are you expecting?

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, a join creates a row for each permutation that match the conditions. You are joining 3 tables. You are saying that for size 1, these tables have:

- `size`: 1 row
- `import_size`: 1 row
- `export_size`: 2 rows

This gives us 1*1*2=2 permutations, which means we get 2 rows. Obviously each contains a different `export_size` record, but what about `size` and `import_size`? The two rows use the same record from both of them. That means that `import_size.weight` appears **twice** - and that's why it's summed twice.

BTW - if both tables had 2 entries for size 1, you'd get 4 permutations and both import and export sizes will be doubled.

The solution: do the aggregation separately for each table and then do the join(not tested):

```
SELECT i.imports, e.exports, s.size
    FROM size AS s
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT size_id,sum(weight) AS imports FROM import_size GROUP BY size_id) AS i ON s.id=i.size_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT size_id,sum(weight) AS exports FROM export_size GROUP BY size_id) AS e ON s.id=e.size_id
```